# How to add logout functionality in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a login functionality using spring security and below is the code:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
    .and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("login.html").permitAll();

    httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/taxi_state?start=*&end=*&zone_id=*").hasRole("USER")
    .and()
    .formLogin().loginPage("login.html").permitAll();
}
```

But I want to have the logout functionality as well. How can I have the logout functionality in my code? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please show what you have tried instead of just asking members to give you free code.

Comment: Well as you are using `HttpSecurity` then does the [logout](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#logout--) not help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `logout` method to configure log-off functionality as shown at the bottom of this example:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity             
          .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/")
                 .permitAll()
             .anyRequest()
                 .authenticated()
             .and()
          .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/login")
             .permitAll()
             .and()
          .logout()
             .permitAll()
         ;
 }
```

This will provide the default configuration for logging out. For instance, the URL will be `/logout` and sessions will be invalidated. You may change the logout URL by invoking the `logoutUrl` method.

Note that view paths such as `"/login"` don't need the `.html` extension. They will typically resolve to `login.html` internally with the default Thymeleaf view configuration.

Comment: I use "/login" .html because I use my own custom login page and your code throws the error near ` .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/")` .So could u help with this?

Comment: @Josh oh. There was an extra dot between httpSecurity and authorizeRequests. Please try it now

Comment: Yeah this works.